# What happens with the events in nested drag drop AddEventListener?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, addeventlistener

I have the following nested addEventListener to keep track of the dragged element and the element i am dragging to.

```
var objects = document.querySelector('.objects');
var destination = document.querySelector('.dest');


objects.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e) {
    console.log("dragstart")
    destination.addEventListener('dragover', function(e2) { e2.preventDefault(); });
    destination.addEventListener('drop', function(e2) {
        console.log("drop")
        console.log(e.target);
        console.log(e2.target);

    })
})
```

```
<style>
  div >div {
    margin: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="objects">
    <div draggable='true' id='o1'>A</div>
  </div>

  <div class="dest">
    <div id='D1' >1</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The first time i am drag and dropping everything seems as i expected, but when i drag and drop a second time, the addEventListener for drop is executed twice, and the third time, three times. Why is that so?
[image]
If i only console.log the drag and drop strings, this behavior of doubling and trippling does't show up. What happens with the events e and e2?

Comment: with your current code, every time the `dragstart` event trigger it added a new event listener to your `destination`. You need to remove the old event listener after your process finished or before adding a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `removeEventListener` to remove the earlier events that were added so that it doesn't get re-added every time it's dragged, in order to do that you just have to store the function separately though

```js
var objects = document.querySelector('.objects');
var destination = document.querySelector('.dest');


function dragFnc(e2) { 
  e2.preventDefault(); 
}
function dropt(e2) {
        console.log("drop")
        console.log(e2.target);
        e2.target.removeEventListener("dragover",dropt)
        e2.target.removeEventListener("drop",dragFnc)
}
objects.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e) {
    console.log("dragstart")
    destination.addEventListener('dragover', dragFnc);
    destination.addEventListener('drop', dropt)
})
```

```html
<style>
  div >div {
    margin: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="objects">
    <div draggable='true' id='o1'>A</div>
  </div>

  <div class="dest">
    <div id='D1' >1</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: excellent, thanks. But what, if i need my first e from the objects.addEventListener in the dropt function? How can i transfer the first event into the second addEventListener?